# Can I detect if some mobile was not able to play some audio file?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, audioformat

I've noticed that some mobile phones are not able to play some video files. Sometimes it's .wav extension, and sometimes some other.

In such cases the app does not crash and no error is generated, but the audio file just silently does not get played.

How to detect such situations? Why is this happening on the first place?

PS. **I need to detect this in Java code - programmatically**

Comment: Check the Hardware Profile for supported Sound Format

Comment: @Lucifer I need to do this programmatically in Java code

Comment: I suggest you only play .ogg files.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I was thinking the same if I do not find a solution. But is there a guarantee that .ogg will play in 100% of cases? I cannot find any doc on this issue. I know it's Linux format (vorbis)

Comment: I'm not sure, yet I believe you should give it a try. ".ogg" is the preferred file format for Android when it comes to playing sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)** read the document, it tells which kind of media files are supported by the android.

For crashing problem please put your code in try...catch block like below,

```
try
{
      // Code to play media file.
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
      // Display a Toast message, "File format doesn't support"
}
```

Comment: Hm I thought of this. But will it trigger when Android OS does not support the file or when a specific device does not support the file? I think the previous so I do not see how this may help me in my case

Comment: when catch block is there to handle the don't worry/

Comment: Oh you mean a general `exception` object. I'll give it a try. it's an old trick but I haven't thought of it :)

Comment: well try...catch block is for that purpose only, to continue execution without exiting the program in middle. @sandalone